# Trigonometric Limit without L'hospital (0/0 kind): $\lim\limits_{x \to \frac\pi6} \ \frac{\sin(x-\frac\pi6)}{\frac{\sqrt3}2-\cos(x)}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x \to \frac\pi6} \ \frac{\sin(x-\frac\pi6)}{\frac{\sqrt3}2-\cos(x)}$$

It is supposed to be $2$ I think. I'm really stuck with this one.

Comment: Try $$\frac{\sin(x-\pi/6)}{\sqrt3/2-\cos(x)}=-\frac{\frac{\sin(x-\pi/6)}{x-\pi/6}}{\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(\pi/6)}{x-\pi/6}}$$

Comment: @5xum Haha. Guess it's getting late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$\lim_{x \to \frac\pi6} \ \frac{\sin(x-\frac\pi6)}{\frac{\sqrt3}2-\cos(x)}
=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(t)}{\frac{\sqrt3}2-\cos(t+\frac\pi6)}.$$
Then use the fact that 
$$\cos\left(t+\frac\pi6\right)=\cos(t)\cos\left(\frac\pi6\right)-\sin(t)\sin\left(\frac\pi6\right)
=\frac{\sqrt3}2\cdot\cos(t)-\frac{1}2\cdot\sin(t).$$

Comment: And if he/she wants to go further, a very limited Taylor expansion around $t=0$ will show not only the limit for such but how it is approached.